# python single file multiple lock issue

Tags: python, multithreading, cron-task, locks

I have a scenario where in there are 2 processes (Log_writer1.py and Log_writer2.py) running (as cron jobs) which are eventually writing to the same log file(test_log_file.txt) as part of the log_event function.
Because of multiple locks, there are inconsistencies and all data are not being stored in the log file.
Is there any way that a single lock can be shared between multiple processes to avoid these inconsistencies. Here are the below code snippets. Kindly suggest

```
Script : test_cifs_log_writer.py
=================================================================================================

def log_event(level, msg, job_log_file,lck):
    lck.acquire()
    for i in range(50):
        with open(job_log_file, 'a') as wr_log:
            print('Now printing message : '+str(msg))
            wr_log.write(str(time.ctime())+' - '+level.upper()+' - '+str(msg)+'\n')
    lck.release()


Script : Log_writer1.py
=================================================================================================

from threading import Thread, Lock
from test_cifs_log_writer import *

lck=Lock()
t1=Thread(target=log_event, args=('info','Thread 1 : msg','test_log_file.txt',lck))
t2=Thread(target=log_event, args=('info','Thread 2 : msg','test_log_file.txt',lck))

lst=[t1,t2]

for thr in lst:
    thr.start()

for thr in lst:
    thr.join()

Script : Log_writer2.py
=================================================================================================

from threading import Thread, Lock
from test_cifs_log_writer import *

lck=Lock()
t1=Thread(target=log_event, args=('info','Thread 3 : msg','test_log_file.txt',lck))
t2=Thread(target=log_event, args=('info','Thread 4 : msg','test_log_file.txt',lck))

lst=[t1,t2]

for thr in lst:
    thr.start()

for thr in lst:
    thr.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not an easy way. Even if you could share a lock, you'd then run into lock contention issues

Either:

- (easiest, just requires an extra step later) have each process write to a separate, uniquely named log file and concatenate them afterwards if you need to.
- (harder, requires an extra process and communication) delegate writing the single log file to a single process that the other processes communicate with. (This is essentially what [`SyslogHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler) does.)
- (worst, slow and lock-contented) have each process lock, open, write, close, unlock the file for each entry they want to write

Comment: concatenating the file with no extra measures can result in data loss.

Comment: @jsbueno No, after the files have been written and closed and so on, concatenating them into a separate file will be just fine. Or is there some other scenario you're thinking about?

Comment: Thanks for assisting on this. I will go with the easiest way as of now :)

Comment: " Or is there some other scenario you're thinking about?"- yes, I suppose the scripts are continuously running, collecting logs or something, and there will be no  "after" they are both done.

Comment: @jsbueno Right, in that case you'd need to add log rotation too – but for a continuously running script, logging would be best handled by something else altogether, e.g. running them via systemd timers and letting journald do its thing...